# cumulative distribution function of special random variable

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

When I see example 2.3.8 in book Elements of
Large-Sample Theory, I have a problem:
That is
P($Y_{n}$=Y)=1-$p_{n}$ and P($Y_{n}$=n)=$p_{n}$.
Obviously, $Y_{n}$ is a piecewise random variable, Then, what is the cumulative distribution function of $Y_{n}$?

Comment: Could you provide exactly what the question states? The question is unclear at present.

Comment: Example 2.3.8 Let
$$
Y_{n}= \begin{cases}Y & \text { with probability } 1-p_{n} \\ n & \text { with probability } p_{n}\end{cases},
$$ Y may be a constant or a random variable.
Then my question is what is the cumulative distribution function of $Y_{n}$?

I have tried to solve this problem with the total probability rule.
That is for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $P(Y_{n}<x)=P(Y_{n}<x|Y_{n}=Y)+P(Y_{n}<x|Y_{n}=n).$  But I am not able to determine the outcome of this conditional probability $P(Y_{n}<x|Y_{n}=Y).$

Answer (score 1):

Presumably what they mean by this definition is that

$$
Y_n =n1\{B_n = 1\}+  Y 1\{B_n = 0\}
$$
where $B_n$ is independent of $Y$ and $P(B_n=1)=p_n = 1-P(B_n=0)$. If so, then by the law of total probability $P(Y_n \le x) = P(Y_n \le x | B_n=0)P(B_n=0)+ P(Y_n \le x | B_n=1)P(B_n=1) =P(Y\le x)(1-p_n) + P(n \le x)p_n.$

Note that this CDF is a mixture of that of $Y$ and a point mass at $n$ of magnitude $p_n$.